# String manipulation - cutting off the last part of an IP address

Tags: php

I want to take the ip address stored in `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` (for instance `127.0.0.1`), and cut off the last part (the numbers after the last dot). The problem I have with this is that I don't know the lenght of the string I'm cutting off (sometimes there's 1 number, sometimes there's more).

I want to store what's not cut off in a variable. Here I call it `$output`.

After looking at the php manual for a while (I'm new to php), I came up with this `$output = substr(strrchr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], '.'), 0);` , but this will only output the last part of the string (in this case, the last number).

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong, and how to fix it?

Comment: Explode by`.` and then implode excluding the last element.

Comment: @AbraCadaver thanks, write that up as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`substr()` is good, but instead of `strrchr()`, use [strrpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) to get the position of the last occurence of `.`:

```
echo substr($string, 0, strrpos($string, '.'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strrpos` in combination with `substr`

```
<?php

$string = '127.0.0.1'; 

//posistion last dot '.
$pos = strrpos($string, '.');

//Return part of a string
$part = substr($string, 0, $pos);

//output
echo $part;
?>
```